# Why does Game code keep running instead of being garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I have this code which creates an anonymous game instance after the window onload event fires.

Since this whole function is anonymous and the reference to the game object is not saved anywhere, I am actually surprised that this game runs at all!

Why is myGame not disposed of after window.onload? 
I know that Garbage Collection does not happen immediately, but I have never seen the myGame instance suddenly disappear at a random moment either. What kind of code inside the Game class would be able to keep the instance from being garbage collected? Is it the references to the DOM?

**Game.js**

```
(function(window){
    window.onload = function() { 
        // create a game instance but don't save the reference anywhere
        var myGame = new Game();
    };

    function Game() {

        var myCar;
        this.name = "Main App";

        this.init = function(){
            this.logMessage("creating a game instance");
        }

        this.logMessage = function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += msg + "</br>";
        }

        this.init();
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: *"I have never seen the myGame instance suddenly disappear at a random moment either"* What evidence do you have that it is kept around? Show the evidence, so we can help you explain what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Game code keep running instead of being garbage collected?

It doesn't. It sets the message and then is immediately eligible for GC. The fact that the message remains showing doesn't mean your game instance is still in memory or its code running.

Nothing in that code is preventing the `Game` *instance* from being GC'd. GC just may not happen unless there's a reason for it (memory pressure, etc.), but with code that simple, a modern engine may well not even need to apply GC (V8, for instance, may allocate your instance *on the stack* and then just pop the stack; if your code kept a reference after `onload` returned, it would copy it to the heap on exit).

> Is it the references to the DOM?

No, references *from* your game instance *to* the DOM won't keep your game instance in memory, because of the direction (*from* your game instance *to* the DOM elements). It would have to be the other way. (Besides, you don't keep any of the references you're retrieving.)

> What kind of code inside the Game class would be able to keep the instance from being garbage collected?

Anything that causes a direct or indirect reference to the game instance. For instance, just changing

```
var myGame = new Game();
```

to

```
window.myGame = new Game();
```

would do it, because now `window` has a property referring directly to the game instance.

Or adding code like this inside `init`:

```
var self = this;
document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerHTML = self.name;
}, false);
```

because now, that DOM element has a reference to that event handler function, which in turn has a reference to the context in which it was created, which has a reference to the `Game` instance.

---

Note that in your code, `Game` (the function) *is* kept around, because the closure assigned to `window.onload` closes over the context in which `Game` is created. We can see that if we dig deep enough in Chrome's heap snapshot:

[image]

...but the `Game` *instance* created and assigned (briefly) to `myGame` is not kept.

---

FWIW, in Chrome, if I run your code and do a heap snapshot and search for instances of `Game`, I don't see any:

[image]

If I modify your code so the instance is retained:

```
window.myGame = new Game();
```

then I do:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So myGame may actually be gone already, it's just that my code is too simple to notice a difference. Suppose I'd add a DOM Button with a listener. Would that prevent the instance from being GC'd, or would the DOM button stop working after a while? (Supposing that the GC does run?)

Comment: @Kokodoko: If you added, say, `var self = this; document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("click", function() {  this.innerHTML = self.name; }, false);` inside `init`, that would keep the instance in memory, because the DOM retains a reference to the handler function, which in turn retains a reference to the context in which it was created, which in turn has a reference to the game instance.